# Is there any way, through the AWS CLI of through boto3, to figure out if a specific instance type - OS combination is available in an AWS region/AZ?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, boto3

I'm getting this error when trying to launch a specific **instance type - OS** combination on AWS, more precisely **t2.medium Windows**:

```
Your requested instance type (t2.medium Windows) is not supported in your requested Availability Zone
```

I know I can switch around and look for different regions and AZs, but I'm trying to come up with a generic solution that lets me detect if a specific region/AZ combo supports what I'm trying to launch.

However, when trying this through the AWS CLI, I don't see a field for the **platform** (aka operating system):

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-types
```

And when selecting the instance type, it doesn't say anything about the OS:

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-types | jq '.InstanceTypes[] | .InstanceType'
```

just returns `t2.medium`, `t2.large`, etc.

Ideally I'd want to do this through the CLI but a boto3 solution would also work, but I don't see anything in the API for this. I also don't see anything in their docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html#AvailableInstanceTypes

It would be kind of sad if I had to launch my specific instance type - OS combo and then had to wait for the launch to fail...

Comment: An alternative would be to try and catch this error, and write some other logic for that

Comment: The more I dig around, that seems like the only option left. A bit sad since you can't really plan ahead and it's also slower.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-type-not-supported-az-error/

Comment: It's super close, but it still doesn't include the OS. Snatching defeat from the jaws of victory, AWS! :-(

Comment: At least for Windows stuff, but probably for other OSes, AWS SSM seems to help, it's the last missing bit: `aws ssm get-parameters --names [AMI name and path] --region us-east-1 --output table` Yay!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61255134/how-to-get-free-tier-ami-in-aws-using-python-with-boto3/61258141#61258141 Hope it helps

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61255134/how-to-get-free-tier-ami-in-aws-using-python-with-boto3/61258141#61258141 Hope it helps

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61255134/how-to-get-free-tier-ami-in-aws-using-python-with-boto3/61258141#61258141 Hope it helps,
r0ck

Answer (score 1):

1. To find Instance Type
   If you are looking to find supported Instance Types in particular region you can go through the following link.
   [describe-instance-type-offerings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-type-offerings.html)

2. To find the supported OS or AMI ID of that particular OS you can create the following lambda functions which I am using to get Windows and Ubuntu OS AMI Id's

> ```
> AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
> Description: CloudFormation Custom Resources for an environment
> Parameters:
>   EnvironmentName:
>     Description: "Environment's name. Max 10 alphanumeric characters."
>     Type: String
>     AllowedPattern: '[a-z0-9]{1,10}'
>
> Resources:
>   GetWindowsAmiLambda:
>     Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
>     Properties:
>       FunctionName: !Sub "${EnvironmentName}_cfn_getwindowsami_lambda"
>       Handler: index.handler
>       Timeout: 30
>       Role: !GetAtt CfnGetAmiRole.Arn
>       Runtime: nodejs12.x
>       Code:
>         ZipFile: !Sub |
>           var response = require('cfn-response');
>           var aws = require('aws-sdk');
>
>           exports.handler = function(event, context) {
>             console.log(event);
>             var validVersions = ['2016','2019'];
>
>             var splitStackArn = event.StackId.split(':');
>             var region = splitStackArn[3];
>             var accountId = splitStackArn[4];
>             var stackName = splitStackArn[5].split("/")[1];
>             var props = event.ResourceProperties;
>             var windowsVersion = props.Version;
>
>             if(!(validVersions.includes(windowsVersion))){
>               returnNull(response.FAILED);
>             }
>
>             var resourceId = props.PhysicalResourceId || "cfn-" + stackName + "-windows-" + windowsVersion + "-ami-" + event.LogicalResourceId;
>
>             var params = {
>               Name: "/aws/service/ami-windows-latest/Windows_Server-" + windowsVersion + "-English-Full-Base"
>             };
>
>             var cb = function(err, resp) {
>               if (err) {
>                 console.log(err, err.stack);
>                 var cfnRespData = { Name: null, ImageId: null, CreationDate: null, RootDeviceName: null, RootDeviceType: null};
>                 response.send(event, context, response.FAILED, cfnRespData, resourceId);
>               } else {
>                 console.log("success");
>                 var cfnRespData = { ImageId: resp.Parameter.Value };
>                 response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, cfnRespData, resourceId);
>               }
>             };
>
>             function returnNull(respResult){
>               var cfnRespData = { Name: null, ImageId: null, CreationDate: null, RootDeviceName: null, RootDeviceType: null};
>               response.send(event, context, respResult, cfnRespData, "");
>             }
>
>             if (event.RequestType != "Delete") {
>               try{
>                 var ssm = new aws.SSM();
>                 ssm.getParameter(params, cb);
>               }catch(e){
>                 console.log(e);
>                 returnNull(response.FAILED);
>               }
>             }else{
>               returnNull(response.SUCCESS);
>             }
>           };
>
>   GetUbuntuAmiLambda:
>     Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
>     Properties:
>       FunctionName: !Sub "${EnvironmentName}_cfn_getubuntuami_lambda"
>       Handler: index.handler
>       Timeout: 30
>       Role: !GetAtt CfnGetAmiRole.Arn
>       Runtime: nodejs12.x
>       Code:
>         ZipFile: !Sub |
>           var response = require('cfn-response');
>           var aws = require('aws-sdk');
>
>           exports.handler = function(event, context) {
>             console.log(event);
>             var validVersions = ['14.04','16.04','18.04','20.04'];
>
>             var splitStackArn = event.StackId.split(':');
>             var region = splitStackArn[3];
>             var accountId = splitStackArn[4];
>             var stackName = splitStackArn[5].split("/")[1];
>             var props = event.ResourceProperties;
>             var ubuntuVersion = props.Version;
>
>             if(!(validVersions.includes(ubuntuVersion))){
>               returnNull(response.FAILED);
>             }
>
>             var resourceId = props.PhysicalResourceId || "cfn-" + stackName + "-ubuntu-" + ubuntuVersion + "-ami-" + event.LogicalResourceId;
>
>             var params = {
>               Owners: ['099720109477'],
>               Filters: [
>                 {
>                   Name: 'name',
>                   Values: [
>                     'ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-*-' + ubuntuVersion + '-amd64-server-????????'
>                   ]
>                 }
>               ]
>             };
>
>             var cb = function(err, resp) {
>               if (err) {
>                 console.log(err, err.stack);
>                 var cfnRespData = { Name: null, ImageId: null, CreationDate: null, RootDeviceName: null, RootDeviceType: null};
>                 response.send(event, context, response.FAILED, cfnRespData, resourceId);
>               } else {
>                 console.log("success");
>                 resp.Images.sort(amiCompareDesc);
>                 var img = resp.Images[0];
>                 var cfnRespData = { Name: img.Name, ImageId: img.ImageId, CreationDate: img.CreationDate, RootDeviceName: img.RootDeviceName, RootDeviceType: img.RootDeviceType };
>                 response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, cfnRespData, resourceId);
>               }
>             };
>
>             function amiCompareDesc(a,b){
>               var d1 = Date.parse(a.CreationDate), d2 = Date.parse(b.CreationDate);
>
>               if(d1 > d2)
>                 return -1;
>               if(d1 < d2)
>                 return 1;
>               return 0;
>             }
>
>             function returnNull(respResult){
>               var cfnRespData = { Name: null, ImageId: null, CreationDate: null, RootDeviceName: null, RootDeviceType: null};
>               response.send(event, context, respResult, cfnRespData, "");
>             }
>
>             var ec2 = new aws.EC2({ region: region });
>
>             if (event.RequestType != "Delete") {
>               try{
>                 ec2.describeImages(params,cb);
>               }catch(e){
>                 console.log(e);
>                 returnNull(response.FAILED);
>               }
>             }else{
>               returnNull(response.SUCCESS);
>             }
>           };
>
>   CfnGetAmiRole:
>     Type: AWS::IAM::Role
>     Properties:
>       RoleName: !Sub "${EnvironmentName}_cfn_getami_lambda_role"
>       AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
>         Version: '2012-10-17'
>         Statement:
>           - Effect: Allow
>             Principal:
>               Service:
>                 - lambda.amazonaws.com
>             Action:
>               - sts:AssumeRole
>       Path: "/"
>       Policies:
>         - PolicyName: root
>           PolicyDocument:
>             Version: '2012-10-17'
>             Statement:
>               - Effect: Allow
>                 Action:
>                   - logs:CreateLogGroup
>                   - logs:CreateLogStream
>                   - logs:PutLogEvents
>                 Resource: arn:aws:logs:*:*:*
>               - Effect: Allow
>                 Action:
>                   - ec2:DescribeImages
>                   - ec2:DescribeImageAttribute
>                   - ssm:GetParameterHistory
>                   - ssm:GetParametersByPath
>                   - ssm:GetParameters
>                   - ssm:GetParameter
>                 Resource: "*"
> Outputs:
>   UbuntuAmiLookup:
>     Description: Cfn lambda for getting latest Ubuntu AMI
>     Value: !GetAtt GetUbuntuAmiLambda.Arn
>     Export:
>       Name: !Sub '${EnvironmentName}-UbuntuAmiLookup'
>   WindowsAmiLookup:
>     Description: Cfn lambda for getting latest Windows AMI
>     Value: !GetAtt GetWindowsAmiLambda.Arn
>     Export:
>       Name: !Sub '${EnvironmentName}-WindowsAmiLookup'
> ```

- Above functions will get latest AMI which we can use as reference while creating Instance.